# How does Java initialize String literal

Tags: java, string, jvm

Javadoc said that:

> The String class represents character strings. All string literals in Java programs, such as "abc", are implemented as instances of this class.

We know that `String` class has two properties namely: `value[]` and `hash`, and String literal are stored in a String pool.

But I am not able to figure out **how that String literal is initialized** before putting to that pool. As if I debug the string literal later, I can see the `value[]` and `hash` is somehow populated.

Does JVM invoke a special instruction?

Comment: Your question text doesn’t match the title - did you mean to ask about string initialization or about string pooling?

Comment: I am asking about how String literal is initialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JVM creates a new string literal object during [constant pool resolution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.1), if the same string has not been put to the string table before by `String.intern` call.

It is not specified how JVM creates and initializes such strings, so JVM may do whatever it wants as long as the result object is a regular `java.lang.String` instance that can be accessed from application code.

As to HotSpot JVM, it does not call any of `String` constructors, it just allocates a new object in Heap and fills in the fields in C++ code, see [`java_lang_String::basic_create`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/574c3b0cf3e5/src/share/vm/classfile/javaClasses.cpp#l164):

```
Handle java_lang_String::basic_create(int length, TRAPS) {
  assert(initialized, "Must be initialized");
  // Create the String object first, so there's a chance that the String
  // and the char array it points to end up in the same cache line.
  oop obj;
  obj = InstanceKlass::cast(SystemDictionary::String_klass())->allocate_instance(CHECK_NH);

  // Create the char array.  The String object must be handlized here
  // because GC can happen as a result of the allocation attempt.
  Handle h_obj(THREAD, obj);
  typeArrayOop buffer;
    buffer = oopFactory::new_charArray(length, CHECK_NH);

  // Point the String at the char array
  obj = h_obj();
  set_value(obj, buffer);
  // No need to zero the offset, allocation zero'ed the entire String object
  assert(offset(obj) == 0, "initial String offset should be zero");
//set_offset(obj, 0);
  set_count(obj, length);

  return h_obj;
}
```

`hash` field of such new object is initialized to zero. The right hash code will be calculated on the first call to `String.hashCode`.

Comment: @apangin from your answer, do you mean "...it does call any of..." or it doesn't call any of?

Comment: @apangin Help me understand with my answer(see below). When I put a break point at that constructor, it does hit and stop at the spot. As per your statement, if none of the constructors are called, 1. how come there's a stop at breakpoint? I tried with two IDEs, both stop at breakpoint. 2. How `value` member is assigned a value as mentioned in OP? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Does JVM invoke a special instruction?

No.  There is no "special" JVM instruction to do that.

The classloading infrastructure will most likely be creating the String objects that correspond to the literals using one of the `String` constructors; e.g. `String(char[])` or `String(byte[])`.  It will be getting the characters or bytes from the "constant pool" area in the ".class" file.

Comment: Tell me which construct it uses. My debug break point does not stop anywhere for the literal I defined

Comment: You can find out which constructor is used by examining the (native code) source code for the JVM.   But setting a breakpoint on it will most likely cause a break for every single string literal that gets loaded by the JVM.

Comment: I tried but I can't find my string is initialized there (but found other string being initialized). That's why I ask this question.

Comment: Which files in the Java source code tree did you look at?

Comment: String.java, isn't it?

Comment: Nope.  The call to the String constructor happens in the native code.  Like I said.   Download the OpenJK source tree, and start searching.  (I am assuming that you are asking this because you want to learn how the JVM works under the hood.  If that is the case, the onus is on you to do the work.)

Comment: But in the end, it will hit the String.class anyway, isn't it? Did I miss something here?

Comment: Well yes.  But you wanted to know >>which<< constructor is used.  (Yes ... you are missing something if you think that looking at the String code will tell you which constructor is used ...)

Comment: The problem is, I placed break point on all String constructors but when debugging it never hit with my declared literal. I saw other Strings only XD Maybe it's too many and I missed somewhere

Comment: *"Maybe it's too many and I missed somewhere"* - Probably.  But like I said, if you really want to know, download the OpenJDK source code and look at it for yourself.

Answer (score -2):

Follow breakpoint on `public String(char value[])` of `String` class.

**Edit**: Whoever downvoted this:

Firstly, did you try as per answer? I had tried and it stops exactly in that method. I had tried with two different IDEs.
Secondly, `value` member(as pointed in OP) is assigned in that method. If you indeed tried, you would have got that. Thirdly, `hash` member(as pointed in OP) is assigned a value on the call to `hashCode()` and `hash` member is assigned a value in it.

Clearly, you haven't tried. If you did, investigation on breakpoint would have led you to answers in OP:

> 1) how that String literal is initialized

and

> 2) ...somehow populated

.

Comment: Sorry for downvoting, but this does not answer a question. It should be a comment at most. If you tried this and saw it work - you could sum up the results of your experiments as an answer. But I guess you've seen something else, since HotSpot JVM does not call String constructor when creating a literal.

Comment: @apangin 
Can you point to specification or any authentic document which says constructor is not called for a string literal? Thanks. BTW, thanks for your explanation for down-vote. A lesson learnt.

Comment: As I've written in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50306053/3448419), it is *not specified* how JVM creates string literals. This is implementation defined. JVM may call the constructor or may not. HotSpot JVM does not - I've added the reference to the source code. Isn't it authentic enough?

Comment: I _suppose_, constructor call _may_ be implemenation specific, as both of us have observations from different JVMs. I'm curious to learn as to how did you find out `java_lang_String::basic_create` is called for creation of a string literal?

Comment: [ConstantPool::resolve_constant_at_impl](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/574c3b0cf3e5/src/share/vm/oops/constantPool.cpp#l623) -> [string_at_impl](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/574c3b0cf3e5/src/share/vm/oops/constantPool.cpp#l671) -> [StringTable::intern](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/574c3b0cf3e5/src/share/vm/oops/constantPool.cpp#l830) -> [java_lang_String::create_from_unicode](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/574c3b0cf3e5/src/share/vm/classfile/symbolTable.cpp#l762) ->  basic_create